# Should one Make routers on client side using react or using express router on server side?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, express, react-router-dom

I`ve just started learning react and read a book. But I dont know how to build application it to look professional.
I read about react-router-dom and I could make different react components for different routes like in the code spinet below. But is that a good way to structure your react app?

```
import React from 'react';
import { Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom'
import Blog from "./Blog";
import Authentication from './Authentication';
import Registration from "./Registration";

import Menu from "./Menu";
import Whoops404 from './Whoops404';

const Router = () =>
    <section className="application">
        <Route component={Menu} />
        <Switch>
                <Route exact path='/' component={Blog} />
                <Route path='/login' component={Authentication} />
                <Route path='/regist' component={Registration} />
                <Route component={Whoops404} />
        </Switch>
    </section>

export default Router;
```

Comment: Yes, you use react router correctly for your app. Express router is used on backend for creating API, which will return some data to your front end application.

Answer (score 1):

`react-router-dom` is to make routes and move between one page to another in the client side which is your **React app** and it doesn't relate to the backend routes which are used to get fetched by `fetch()` method or `axios` package to get the data , those data used to be rendered on the frontend. I hope i could clearify the idea.

Comment: Yes, of course but I read that the whole state of SPA should be in one place.
But using react-router-dom I will create difrent react component to different route.
That`s why I was confused.

Comment: Components is the parts when gathered , going to make your page or the app . You make 2 components and a route for each  or a component nested in a component and 1 route in that case .

Comment: But I made 5 components?

Comment: It's not about the numbers of the components..it is about how you manage your app